# non-axiomatizable logics

Tags: logic, model-theory, propositional-calculus

Hope you're all doing well. My question is about non-axiomatizable logics. My understanding is that a "logic" (the mathematical structure) is just another word for a "propositional calculus" as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus. (see the formal defn. under "general definition of a propositional calculus.") It seems like this definition inherently depends on axioms, and thus is intuitively "axiomatized."

**Background:**

Say we look at the logic S4, which we can think of(alternatively to the rigorous definition in the above wiki article) as a set of wffs in a specific language $L$ ($L$ is basically the propositional language augmented with some modal operators $\Box$ and $\Diamond$ and with a suitable definition of grammatically correct expressions, i.e. wffs in the language). This set of wffs (S4) contains the tautologies of propositional logic, but also some additional axioms and any wffs in $L$ that can be obtained by using the inference rule $\textit{modus ponens}$. (See http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/ for these additional axioms).

Please correct me if i'm wrong about any of this; I'd appreciate it. In my reading I've come across the idea of a non-axiomatizable logic. (under definition 17 page 139 of http://individual.utoronto.ca/philipkremer/onlinepapers/DTL.pdf) It looks like the concept is quite common, i.e. http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/malq.19610070113/abstract. As I said, the wiki definition of a logic seems to be inherently axiomatizable.

**My question:**

Is there a (relatively simple) example of a non-axiomatizable logic? I've tried googling it, but nothing too useful has come up yet. Is there somewhere I can learn more about it? Thank you for any help/clarification!

Sincerely,

Vien

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, *there is*. One such classic example is *second-order logic*, whose semantics can be given, but for which you can prove there is no axiomatization. I posted some resources [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390819/is-second-order-logic-even-a-logic/390882#390882) in case you're interested (but just FYI, you need to already be familiar with first-order semantics to understand the significance of second-order logic).

Comment: Does it mean that you can not prove theorems syntactically (like modus ponens, turnstile symbol) in second-order logic? So all proofs have to be based on models (double turnstile symbol).

Comment: You can prove *some* logical truths syntactically (logical truths being, for the sake of convenience here, sentences that are true in every model), but you cannot prove *all* of them in any proposed second-order proof system. So you could design a proof system to capture some SOL theorems, but not all of them.

Comment: do you mean that there is no *complete* proof system for SOL?

Comment: Yes, this is one way to put it. I hesitate to say this exactly, just because some people phrase it as saying SOL has *no* proof system (some people have the philosophical disposition that a putative proof system for a logic $L$ cannot be *bona fide* proof system for $L$ unless it's complete; others disagree). But that's just a philosophical point, rather than a mathematical point.

Comment: You are on mathematical portal. I think you should be precise, discussion about philosophy is other thing and you can always defend your point. In my opinion it is better than concealing it.